# it is possible to fill an array from 0 to n when inizializing?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin, initialization

```
val generatedArray = IntArray(10) { i -> i + 1 }
```

`generatedArray`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want the array to start with 0

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Depending on what do you need this array for, it could be a better idea to use range instead of an array. Then the solution is just: `0..10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you start with zero and want to go to the Nth number, your array would have to be of size N + 1.

Second, this would be pretty simple -

```
val generatedArray = IntArray(11) { i -> i }
```

This would generate the requested array -
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Answer (score 1):

just use i instead of i+1

`val generatedArray = IntArray(10) { i -> i }`